# How to get byte code from deployed contract in

Tags: web3js, ether, bytecode

I want to get the byte code of a deployed contract. How can I get it? Is there a special function in web3.js? I haven't found any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetcode), you can use this method:

> web3.eth.getCode(addressHexString [, defaultBlock] [, callback])

Where `addressHexString` is the address your contract was deployed at.